# Liferay Migrating User from legacy database & LDAP

Tags: liferay, liferay-6.2

I am migrating data into Liferay from legacy database for which I have written script to programmatically push data into Liferay's user as I see fit.

Now authentication happens with LDAP and some basic details of user are also in LDAP which is supposed to be synced. Will it cause problem if I migrate users to Liferay and also sync basic details of user from LDAP after migration. Will the LDAP sync try to insert new record instead of updating the existing record in database(earlier from migration)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you set the `Authentication Search Filter`, the `Import Search Filter` and the `User Mapping` in the LDAP settings correctly, it should find the appropriate user during synchronization.

Depending on the setup of your LDAP you can use the screen name or the email address of the user as place holder in the `Authentication Search Filter`:

```
(cn=@email_address@)
```

or

```
(cn=@screen_name@)
```

The `Import Search Filter`is just to constrain the possible values, e.g.:

```
(&(objectClass=inetOrgPerson))
```

And the `User Mapping` should at least contain the correct mapping for the screen name, e.g. `cn`.